# Passing the value of an HTML text input (without runat server) from a user control to code behind

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-controls

I'm going crazy trying to send the value of an HTML text input (without runat="server") from a user control to a code behind. I get an empty string with no error. The steps are as follows:

2. User clicks on the ImageButton with ID="name_btn".
3. The value must be passed to the code behind. I'm testing to see if the value is passed by using the page load (if (IsPostBack)) and the button click function but still NO VALUE in both.

Note that for some other reason, I don't want the text input to run on the server so I don't want to add runat="server". Any help please?

User Control page (name.ascx)

```
<input type="text" ID="name" />
<asp:ImageButton runat="server" ID="name_btn" OnClick="name_Click" ImageUrl="~/icon-ok.png" />
```

User control - Code behind (name.ascx.cs)

```
public string nameBox;
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (IsPostBack)
        {
            nameBox = Request.Form["name"];
            Response.Write("Name: " + nameBox);
        }
    }

protected void name_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
           nameBox = Request.Form["name"];
           Response.Write("Name: " + nameBox);
    }
```

Master Page

```
<uc:name runat="server" ID="UCname" />
```

Comment: You will never receive the value of textbox in codebehind if you have not opted to make it a server control.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would imagine that there is a bit of a conflict with what you are trying to do. For example, on the server you are using Request.Form[""] to get the html input element but you are requesting it by the id attribute. Request.Form supports finding elements by index and name.

So have you tried adding a name="" to the html input element?

Comment: You made my day.... I took for granted that Request.Form looks for the ID like most asp.net controls but I've missed the fact that it's just a simple HTML input.... Thanks

Answer (score 2):

you should add a name attribute to your input tag, example:

```
<input type="text" id="name" name="name"/>
```

then you can use:

```
 if (IsPostBack)
 {
   nameBox = Request.Form["name"];
   Response.Write("Name: " + nameBox);
 }
```

The `Request.Form(element)[(index)|.Count]` Parameters:

### **element**

The **name** of the form element from which the collection is to retrieve values.

### **index**

An optional parameter that enables you to access one of multiple values for a parameter. It can be any integer in the range 1 to Request.Form(parameter).Count.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass the value to codebehind using a javascript in two ways.
1. Onclick of your image button call a javascript.
Set your textbox value in __EVENTARGUMENT and call __doPostback(). And in pageload you can check the value in __EVENTARGUMENT.

2. From the javascript you can directly call a Function in your server using PageMethods. Here your function must be a WebMethod.

Comment: But not if you are giving postback for your button